# I am getting 404 redirection on pages from community_auth

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I tried installing `community_auth` with all their guidelines. I don't know where I am going wrong. Only the `/login` route is working. Other routes they are giving `404 error`.

Now the thing is they have told to add only `$route[LOGIN_PAGE]='examples/login'` thus targeting only one route for the Controller.

So I am asking do we have to write different routes ourself. or am I doing something wrong.
This is my config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'User';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route[LOGIN_PAGE] = 'examples/login';

$route['warehouse-provider'] = 'user/warehouse_provider';
$route['warehouse-providers'] = 'user/warehouse_provider_redirect';
$route['terms-of-service'] = 'user/terms_of_service';
$route['frequently-asked-questions'] = 'user/faq';
$route['faq'] = 'user/faq_redirect';
$route['about-us'] = 'user/about_us';
$route['getting-started'] = 'user/geting_start';
$route['privacy-policy'] = 'user/privacy_policy';

$route['contact_geting_started'] = 'user/contact_geting_started';
$route['contact_maneger'] = 'user/contact_maneger';

$route['search'] = 'user/search';
$route['mail-chimp'] = 'user/mail_chimp';
$route['warehouse-network'] = 'user/warehouse_network';
$route['(:any)'] = 'user/warehouse_network_detailing/';
$route['preview/(:any)'] = 'user/preview/$1';
$route['(:any)/(:num)'] = 'user/warehouse_network_detailing/';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'user/web_facility/$2';
$route['(:any)/(:any)/review/new'] = 'user/review';
//$route['404_override'] = 'user/error_404';
// $route['warehouse-network/detail/(:any)'] = 'user/web_facility/$1';
// $route['warehouse-network/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'user/warehouse_network_detailing/$1/$2/$3';
// $route['warehouse_network_detailing/(:any)'] = 'user/warehouse_network_detailing/$1';
```

Comment: can you show your `routes.php`?

Comment: @SofyanThayf this is my routes.php. I have edited my question

Comment: no, community auth only need the login route, and also you have the rule order incorrect, `$route['(:any)']` should be the last rule, `$route['(:any)/(:any)']` above it, then `$route['(:any)/(:any)/review/new']`, `$route['(:any)/(:num)']`, etc

Comment: @HastaDhana Thanks for your help. But still I am not able to open other routes with only login route being written.